# Clean install of Debian 8.3 missing PermitRootLogin in ssh_config (can't ssh root login)

Tags: ssh

I just installed a new vm of Debian from a netinst ISO, everything went fine.

But when I went into `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to change the PermitRootLogin setting to yes, it wasn't there, so I added it, `PermitRootLogin yes`, then restarted ssh, tried to login, it failed.

Keeps saying `Permission denied, please try again.`

I'm using the right password, as I use it to log into the VM directly.

Comment: Oh there is a unix stackexchange, I had no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oooh, sorry, rookie mistake, I was actually editing `ssh_config` file, not `sshd_config`.

This is what happens when you don't use linux for ages.

It's working as expected now.